# On Buchstab et al's "forgotten" sieve and the Goldbach conjecture for certain integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, goldbach-type-problems

There is a somewhat forgotten sieve-theoretic approach to the Goldbach conjecture, due to Buchstab et al, see e.g. pp.247-248 of R.D. James.

On p.247, James defines some function $F$ such that for any fixed $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and even $x \geq 6$:

1. $F(x ; 2, a, 1) = F(x; 2)$ with $a=1$ is the number of positive integers $n \leq x$ such that $n \equiv a\pmod{2}$. Thus $F(x; 2) = x/2$.
2. $F(x; 2, √x, a)=F(x; 2, √x)$ with $a=1$ is the number of odd positive integers $n<x$ (without double counting $n$ and $x-n$), such that each of $n$ and $x-n$ is either a prime or equal to 1. Thus if it could be shown that $F(x; 2, √x) \geq 2$, it would follow that there exists at least one representation $x= n+(x-n)$ whereby each of $n$ and $x-n$ is either a prime or equal to 1. Thus if $x-1$ is composite, it would suffice to show that $F(x; 2, √x) = F(x; 2, √x) \geq 1$.

On the bottom of p.248, James states that
$$
F(x; 2, √x) = F(x; 2) - 2\sum_{r=1}^{k} F(x; 2p_r, p_{r-1}) = x/2 - 2\sum_{r=1}^{k} F(x; 2p_{r}, p_{r-1})
,$$
where $p_i$ denotes the $i$-th odd prime $\leq √x$. T. Kubalalika, in his preprint [2], lets $6 \leq x \equiv 2\pmod{4}$ where $x-1$ is composite. Now suppose that $x$ is a counterexample to Goldbach, so that $F(x; 2, √x)=0$. Putting this into the above equality gives
$$
x/2 = 2\sum_{r=1}^{k} F(x; 2p_r, p_{r-1}),
$$
contradicting the fact that $x/2$ is odd. One therefore deduces that if $x\equiv 2\pmod{4}$ and $x-1$ is composite, then $x$ is a sum of two primes.

My question is, given the strength of Buchstab et al's sieve (as evidenced by how easily it leads to a proof of the above result), are there any modern improvements to it, such that it could possibly lead to even more powerful results ? A quick Google search seems to suggest that the sieve became forgotten as soon as the Hardy-Littlewood circle method lead to Vinogradov's 3-primes theorem.

**References**

[1] R. D. James, "[Recent progress in the Goldbach problem](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1949-55-03/S0002-9904-1949-09180-2/S0002-9904-1949-09180-2.pdf)" Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society 55, 246-260 (1949), [MR0028893](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0028893), [Zbl 0034.02301](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0034.02301).

[2] T. Kubalalika, "[On the binary Goldbach conjecture for certain even integers](https://figshare.com/articles/preprint/On_the_binary_Goldbach_conjecture/21342042)", figSHARE preprint.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, because my question is inspired by the sheer simplicity of the given proof, which certainly doesn't require a journal reviewer to check.

Comment: "how easily it leads to a proof of the above result" <-- are you saying it easily leads to a proof of the Goldbach conjecture? I don't know what else you could mean, and if you don't mean this, then you shouldn't cite a random preprint that claims a proof of a monumental result in short order. But if you do mean a proof of Goldbach, then I think your source is mistaken.

Comment: @DavidRoberts "The above result" appears to be: given x = 4k+2 with 4k+1 composite, we have that x is the sum of two primes. This is written below the final displayed equation, preceding "the above result".

Comment: $F(x;2)$ is not equal to $x/2$, but rather to $\lfloor x/2\rfloor$ (if $a$ is even) or $\lfloor (x+1)/2\rfloor$ (if $a$ is odd).

Comment: @TerryTao, in the Goldbach case, one has $a=1$ (forgot to include this in the initial post), so that $F(x; 2)$ is the floor of $ (x+1)/2$, which is indeed $x/2$.

Comment: The floor of $(x+1)/2$ is not equal to $x/2$ when $x$ is odd.  For instance the floor of $(3+1)/2$ is $F(3;2)=2$, not $3/2$.

Comment: @TerryTao, $x$ was specified in the post to be even.

Comment: Ah, OK, now I see where the real problem lies.  The expression $2 F(x; 2p_r, p_{r-1})$ in James' paper is not necessarily even!  As mentioned in that paper, this expression is really shorthand for $F(x; 2p_r, p_{r-1}; a') + F(x; 2p_r, p_{r-1}; a'')$ for two (not necessarily equal) integers $a',a''$, and so can be the sum of two different numbers rather than the sum of the same number twice.  Basically, James is abusing notation somewhat and one should be wary of blindly applying the usual laws of arithmetic here.

Comment: The first paper referenced by OP is basically talking about the Buchstab's identity in a general context compared to Buchstab's application of it in Goldbach's problem, but it is still more specific than the version presented in modern texts such as Halberstam & Richert's _Sieve Methods_ and Friedlander & Iwaniec's _Opera de Cribro_.

Comment: @TerryTao Such abuse of notations are quite common in early works (e.g Brun, Rademacher, and Buchstab) on the development of combinatorial sieve. It was not until Halberstam & Richert that a good set of notation is introduced.

Comment: @Terry Tao, James is not abusing notation. Indeed, carefully note the condition $n \equiv a'$ (mod $dp_k$) and $n \equiv a''$ (mod $dp_k$). Thus one has $a' \equiv a$ (mod $dp_k)$, so the number of positive integers $n \equiv a'$ (mod $dp_k$) is exactly equal to the number of positive integers $n \equiv a''$ (mod $dp_k$). Hence $F(x, dp_k, p_{k-1}, a') = F(x, dp_k, p_{k-1}, a'')$. One then applies this equality into James' equation $(2.5)$ to obtain $(2.6)$.

Comment: If you read even more carefully, this line of James' paper is interpreted as "$n \equiv a' (\hbox{ mod } dp_k)$" **OR** "$n \equiv a'' (\hbox{ mod } dp_k)$": James is **not** claiming that $a'$ and $a''$ give the same congruence class (if this was his intent, why would he list the same class twice instead of just once?  Also, given that he subtracts both terms separately in (2.5), he is clearly viewing these conditions as being disjoint, which incidentally is another slight abuse of notation.).

Comment: ... actually, I guess they are disjoint, since $a' \equiv a_k \hbox{ mod } p_k$, $a'' \equiv b_k \hbox{ mod } p_k$, and $a_k \not \equiv b_k \hbox{ mod } p_k$ (which in particular explicitly demonstrates that $a' \not \equiv a'' \hbox{ mod } dp_k$).

Comment: @TerryTao, we only have $a_k \neq b_k$, not $a_k$ incongruent to $b_k$ mod $p_k$.

Comment: If the argument outlined in the question worked, it would not only show that each $x\equiv2\pmod4$ is a sum of two primes or $1$ + prime, it would actually show that the number of representations of $x$ in this way is odd. But this is easily checked to be false: to begin with, $6=5+1=3+3$ has two representations, as does $10=7+3=5+5$, etc.

Comment: @user493772 James selects $a_k=0$ and $b_k=x$ if $p_k \not | x$ and $a_k = 0$; and $b_k \neq x \hbox{ mod } p_k$ if $p_k | x$.  In either case we have $a_k \not \equiv b_k \hbox{ mod } p_k$, hence also $a' \not \equiv a'' \hbox{ mod } dp_k$.

Comment: In any event, James very explicitly states that his equation (2.6) should only be interpreted "symbolically" rather than literally, i.e., he explicitly admits to an abuse of notation.  (Such abuse is fine as long as one only wishes to obtain upper or lower bounds on sieve-theoretic quantities, which is how sieve theory is actually used in practice; basically, James is implicitly implementing what we would nowadays call interval arithmetic.  But it will lead to major errors if one tries to apply such symbolic equations to understand the parity of the number of solutions.)

Comment: @TerryTao, you probably mean that $x$ is incongruent to $b_k$ mod $p_k$, since $b_k < p_k<x$. Anyway, I guess that's a minor typo. However, equation (2.7) of James says $$F(x; d, p_k) = F(x ; d) - \cdots + 4\sum_{s=1}^{k} \sum_{s=1}^{r-1} F(x; dp_r p_s) + (-2)^k F(x; dp_k p_{k-1}...p_2 p_1).$$ Are those powers of $2$ due to abusebof notation too ? Because by exactly the same argument, one arrives at the same result. It should also be noted that those powers of $2$ played a crucial role in the subsequent asympotics of Rademacher et al (James, pp.249-252).

Comment: Yes, (2.7) is derived from (2.6) and should therefore also be interpreted symbolically.  As I said, as long as one is only using these symbolic equations to derive upper and lower bounds (or asymptotics), this abuse of notation is relatively safe; but it is **not** safe to use these equations for parity analysis.  As TravorLZH mentioned, this rather confusing notation has long been retired; modern treatments of sieve theory often focus more directly on the upper and lower bounds provided by sieves, rather than on the exact count of any given sieve, so that such misinterpretations are avoided.

Comment: For instance, a literal interpretation of (2.7) would suggest that $F(x;d,p_k)$ and $F(x;d)$ have the same parity, which is not true in general as Emil already pointed out.

Comment: One should interpret any given term such as $F(x;dp_k p_{k-1} \dots p_1)$ as attaining a range of values rather than a single value (or, if one uses an interval arithmetic interpretation, as an interval of values).  An expression such as $(-2)^k F(x;dp_k p_{k-1} \dots p_1)$ should then be interpreted as $(-1)^k$ times the sum of $2^k$ possible values of $F(x;dp_k p_{k-1} \dots p_1)$, which are not necessarily equal to each other.  The modern use of asymptotic notation such as $O()$ is in a similar spirit; for instance $O(1)+O(1)$ refers to the sum of two possibly distinct bounded quantities.

Comment: ... in particular, it would be an error to assume that a quantity of the form $O(1)-O(1)$ necessarily vanishes, because the two separate instances of the $O(1)$ notation could refer to different quantities.  In a similar spirit, it would be an error to assume that symbolic expressions such as $(-2)^k F(x;dp_k p_{k-1} \dots p_1)$ in James' paper are necessarily even.

Comment: @TerryTao, makes sense now. Thanks for the patient explanations ! I wonder do you have lecture notes (on your blog) on the modern treatment of these sieve techniques ? The standard books like Iwaniec are not exactly easy to access.

Comment: I do have some sieve theory notes on my blog at https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/254a-notes-4-some-sieve-theory/

Comment: @TerryTao, thank you very much !

Comment: If your only interest was in the old result, and the little lemma, then why bring up the surely wrong claimed proof of Goldbach? If your intent was really to try to check a step in the preprint, then that is skirting the edge of what MO is for. It is best to be clear and open about your intent. I just can't figure out the motivation here.

Comment: @mme then why bring up the short preprint claiming to prove Goldbach?

Comment: Earlier question from OP on James & Goldbach: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433466/how-does-equation-2-6-follow-from-2-5-in-this-classical-paper-of-r-d-james

Comment: @DavidRoberts, the short preprint was the motivation behind the question. I was curious that if Buchstab et al's sieve is that powerful, it should have a more powerful improvement which i couldn't find in the literature. Of course, the proof was based on the misleading abuse of notation in James' paper, but any non-number theorist could have been mislead by it at first read. I don't think I need to explain myself to you though, because the motivation of my question is clear and sincere. I therefore think that replying any further to your comments is not worth my time and effort, so i won't.

Comment: @user493772 if the author of that preprint was misled by notation, then if I were you I would re-evaluate whether their work is worth spending time to understand. Claims of proofs of big conjectures abound, and one can spend a lot of time finding where they are wrong. I think the question as it stands is fine, and you've had a lot of good advice and answers here, but there are better things to do than do research by studying the errors in others' over-ambitious claims.

Comment: @Gerry yes indeed. There are better things to do with one's time than try to figure this stuff out.

Comment: @David Roberts, well, as I said in the question linked by Gerry, the author has a much more serious preprint: https://figshare.com/articles/preprint/Untitled_Item/14776146 being carefully evaluated by some Fields Medalist at my institution, that's why i even read their partial Goldbach paper in the first place. Concerning the misleading notation in James, notice that even Terry Tao didn't notice it at first. Anyway, had already retired from this discussion. Cheers !

Comment: For anyone wondering, the "much more serious preprint" is a claimed 3-page disproof of the RH, currently sitting at version 172.

Comment: @David Roberts, "much more serious", because i have seen with my own eyes a Fields recipient analytic number theorist reading it line-by-line a few times, and he even mentioned it at some point. Last time I checked, you weren't competent in analytic number theory, so i would rather take the authoritative opinion of former.

Comment: @user493772 I hope that we can all benefit from his analysis soon, if you report it back here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The result (aka Buchstab's identity) you mentioned is not forgotten. In modern sieve theory texts such as Halberstam & Richert's *Sieve Methods* and Friedlander & Iwaniec's *Opera de Cribro*, the identity is written as

$$
S(\mathcal A,z)=S(\mathcal A,w)-\sum_{w\le p<z}S(\mathcal A_p,p)
$$

where $S(\mathcal A,z)$ counts the integers in $\mathcal A$ that are free of prime divisors $<z$.

One of its generalization (Kuhn's weighted sieve) is used to prove Chen's theorem. When $N$ is a positive even integer, $\mathcal A=\{N-p:p\le N\}$, we have

$$
\begin{aligned}
r_{1,2}(N)&=\#\{p\le N:n-p\text{ prime or product of two primes}\} \\
&>S(\mathcal A,N^{1/10})-
\frac12\sum_{N^{1/10}\le p<N^{1/3}}S(\mathcal A_p,N^{1/10})-\frac\Omega2+O(N^{9/10})
\end{aligned}\tag1
$$

in which

$$
\Omega=\#\{p\le N:N-p=p_1p_2p_3,N^{1/10}\le p_1<N^{1/3}\le p_2<(N/p_1)^{1/2}\}.
$$

By evaluating the right hand side using Jurkat-Richert's theorem and Selberg's sieve, Chen found out that for large $N$ there is

$$
r_{1,2}(N)>{0.67N\over\log^2N}\prod_{2<p|N}{p-1\over p-2}\prod_{p>2}\left(1-{1\over(p-1)^2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks ! (+1). Didn't know that this was Chen's approach. Do you have a link to Chen's paper ?

Comment: [This link](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/The_Goldbach_Conjecture.html?id=VAY9nTreXkcC&redir_esc=y) points to a collection of works (including Chen's) related to Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: @user493772 you can also find a full treatment of Chen's theorem and more in Friedlander and Iwaniec's book "Opera de Cribro".

Comment: @Stanley, okay. But i was looking for something more easily accessible, e.g. arXiv preprint.

Comment: The readability of the original paper is quite terrible. I have written a Chinese account [here](https://www.zhihu.com/question/282686634/answer/2353269096) if it helps anybody.